# choosing between a Windows service and a web app

Tags: asp.net, windows-services

We have an ASP.NET website where user adds items to database. 
There are several sites on same server, each with its own database.

I need to implement a mechanism to check database for the state of each item. 
If item is unprocessed, submit it to a third party web-service.

I see two options:

1. put the code in a webapp
2. put the code in a Windows service

The first option has the advantage that the code knows which database to connect to.

With Windows service, it has to be aware of all databases, so it's harder to maintain. Also, if I have only one Windows service, it will have to use threads to process items in each database in parallel.

Maybe there's another way beside these two?

What are the other issues, and what would you recommend?
Please explain your choice.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a good place for a message queue to be involved.  Each item would be wrapped into a message and placed in the queue.  The "item processor" (a service?) would subscribe to the queue and perform some work using each item as it arrives.  How the messages get placed on the queue is up to you, but for an example you could have each site publish the "new item" message to the queue.

Queues can be a bit of an intimidating concept at first, but frameworks such as [MassTransit](http://masstransit-project.com/) can help.  Well worth learning.

Comment: This was my initial reaction as well.

Comment: Yes, a queue-like mechanism is needed. What I need is some hints what to choose. I will take a look to MassTransit, thanks for mentioning it. I worked with MSMQ some time ago. Not sure what is the current state of MSMQ today. Please see my comment to the other post above to get a better idea what I am doing.

Comment: by the way, even with MassTransit, as I mentioned in my question, I still need to choose where to put it. So if you could please suggest something would be great.

Comment: You can host the queue processor(s) anywhere.  I think it is most appropriate to wrap it into a Windows service but you could run it in a web application if required.  MSMQ is still relevant.  Frameworks such as MassTransit and NServiceBus abstract away the plumbing and make development and testing easier.

Answer (score 0):

I believe Windows Service is a good option compared to a web app, mainly because a web app would have to be triggered manually by someone, while a Windows Service can be running at all times, checking for updates.

There's another option, if you have access to each of the existing site's code.  Why not write a Web Service that will submit data to your third party web service.  Then in each of the existing web sites, modify the logic that stores changes in the database to also post the changes to your custom Web Service (or even skip the custom WS and call the third party directly).

Comment: I see different issues with posting directly to the third-party web-service. I oversimplified the idea, but basically it's a process which requires uploading videos, starting encoding jobs, getting the encoding job status, etc (it's the Azure Media Services). I need to think about a resume mechanism after site restarts. Instead of posting directly, I see it easier to just fire each step as necessary and only poll for states from the Azure Media Services.

Comment: aren't there any other options beside the windows service? I see for example in IIS 7.5 there is a Start Mode option for app and pool called 'AlwaysRunning'. It looks like what I need. http://blogs.iis.net/wadeh/archive/2012/05/01/application-initialization-part-2.aspx

Comment: the sad thing is this feature is available only in applicationHost.config